# Line up equations

Tags: math-mode

I want to line up my two equations by the two first equal signals so I wrote this

```
\begin{align}
    \left\
       \begin{matrix}
       \Delta l &= \Delta l_1 + \Delta l_2\\
       N &= N_1(\Delta l_1)=N_2(\Delta_2)\\
       \end{matrix}\right.
\end{align}
```

But I'm getting this:
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that reproduces the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use an inner math environment along with `cases`

[image]

In this case you don't really need to use `align` and simply `equation` would yield identical results as above

### Notes:

- As what you have clearly is *not* a matrix you should *not* use the `matrix` environment.

---

### Code: `align`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \begin{cases}
    \begin{aligned}
       \Delta l &= \Delta l_1 + \Delta l_2\\
              N &= N_1(\Delta l_1)=N_2(\Delta_2)\\
    \end{aligned}
    \end{cases}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

### Code: `equation`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
    \begin{aligned}
       \Delta l &= \Delta l_1 + \Delta l_2\\
              N &= N_1(\Delta l_1)=N_2(\Delta_2)\\
    \end{aligned}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the reason for the `aligned` environment inside the cases environment?

Comment: @Bernard -- the question asked for the two equals signs to be aligned.  `cases` doesn't ordinarily do that; it aligns the lines at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

If you like matrix-like tools, maybe `array` will be suitable for you.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\[
\left\{
\begin{array}{@{}r@{\;=\;}l}
       \Delta l & \Delta l_1 + \Delta l_2\\
       N & N_1(\Delta l_1)=N_2(\Delta_2)\\
       \end{array}
\right.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

`@` kills `\arraycolsep`, adding its argument instead.

Answer (score 2):

I have another idea, maybe `split` will be suitable for you.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{equation}
 \left\{
   \begin{split}
   \Delta l &= \Delta l_1 + \Delta l_2\\
   N &= N_1(\Delta l_1)=N_2(\Delta_2)\\
   \end{split}\right.
 \end{equation}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

One can have a slightly simpler syntax with the `empheq` package (which loads m`mathtools`, hence `amsmath`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}[left=\empheqlbrace]
    \!\begin{aligned}
       Δ l &= Δ l_1 + Δ l_2\\
        N &= N_1(Δ l_1)=N_2(Δ_2)
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why `empheq`? Just `\left\{\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}\right.` is sufficient.

Comment: @egreg: I think that it's more expressive and (slightly) simpler to use the optional argument to the equation environment, that's why.